# iPhone-Only App, when running on iPad which iPhone does it renders?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

which iPhone does the iPad 10.5" renders when it runs an iPhone-only app?
(if some one could give more information also about the 12.9" and etc... would be great too)

Comment: You could very easily find this out for yourself by running an iPhone app in an iPad simulator.

Answer (score 1):

The screen point resolution is reported as 375x667 or a 4.7" screen.
This also equates to an iPhone 8 or an iPhone 8+ in display zoom mode.

See PaintCode's guide for more details on display zoom mode.
https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Answer (score 0):

The 12.9" iPad Pro runs iPhone apps as a 4.7" iPhone (8, 7, 6S, etc).

All other iPads run iPhone apps as a 3.5" (4S, 4, etc).

You can easily find this out yourself by running an iPhone app in the various simulators.